# How to define generic proto message

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying to use proto message format to register eventing in big query. Currently i create different message structs for different events which leads to creation of different tables. The problem with this is if i want to add some more data in same event I need to create a new table as schema has changed (I am not sure of any other way without creating a new table). So for this case I was thinking of creating a generic message that can use used.

Currently one possibilty is using something like this

```
message GenericAnalytics{
    string event_name = 1;
    repeated string data = 2;
}
```

I will use different `event_name` to add rows to the same table.

I can use this struct for all eventing but problem is it will be stored in string type. Is there any better way to this?

Comment: "generics" in the templates sense doesn't exist in protobuf; you could look at "oneof", "Any", or at worst case use "bytes" instead of "string" (since protobuf data is binary, unless you're using the JSON layer)

Comment: @MarcGravell ok, will look at them. Thaks :D